# fetch() in fetch event handler not trigger fetch event in service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

```js
function fetchHandler(evt) {
    console.log('request:' + evt.request.url);
    dealWithRequest(evt);
}

addEventListener("fetch", fetchHandler);

function dealWithRequest(evt){
    fetch('./cgi_data.json,function(){});
}
```

fetch() in fetch event handler not trigger fetch event.

Comment: what is the fetch event?

Comment: You are missing a single quote `fetch('./cgi_data.json',function(){});` after `json`.

Answer (score 2):

You're right. No request (in particular `fetch()`) generated from a service worker is intercepted by the same or other service worker.